# "Failed to delete source temp directory" error when using maven

Tags: maven

I have the following in the pom file:

```
<project>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>com.worksap.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>company-framework-autoindex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>
      <mode>offline</mode>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>collect-index-generator-related-classes</id>
       <goals>
         <goal>collect</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
     <execution>
       <id>package-online-offline-job</id>
       <goals>
         <goal>package</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
                <groupId>com.worksap.company</groupId>
                <artifactId>company-framework-autoindex-normal-batch</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <classifier>all-in-one</classifier>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
       <groupId>com.worksap.company</groupId>
      <artifactId>company-framework-autoindex-offline</artifactId>
       <version>${project.version}</version>
       <classifier>all-in-one</classifier>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
 </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

When I run the following command : `mvn clean install` or `mvn install`, I get this error:

```
49177 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal framework-autoindex-maven-plugin:17.02-SNAPSHOT:collect (collect-index-generator-related-classes) on project hue-com-ifx-dto: Failed to delete source temp directory: ~\hue-com-ifx-dtos\ifx-dto\target\index-generator-related-temp-classes\: Unable to delete file: ~\ifx-dto\target\index-generator-related-temp-classes\serializer.properties -> [Help 1]
```

I have tried to delete `ifx-dto\target\index-generator-related-temp-classes`. Also, I have tried restarting the machine so that no other processes are operating on the file. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are falling [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/faq.html):

> Some files-generating plugins can generate their files outside of the
>   default directories being deleted by the clean plugin. You should add
>   the location of such files in the clean plugin configuration or change
>   the configuration of those plugins to put their files inside the
>   project.build.directory which is by default, the target directory.

[Delete Additional Files Not Exposed to Maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html) may help you.

Comment: Actually, I face the same error even when I use `mvn install`.